# TFS 2015 Build Error While building Asp.Net Core Project

Tags: tfs-2015

I am trying to configure CICD using TFS on premises. I am able to build .net projects but not able to build .net core projects. Getting below error from TFS while building .net core project.

```
GETSDKTOOLINGINFO(0,0): Error : The project is configured to use .NET Core SDK version 1.0.0-preview2-003131 which is not installed or cannot be found. These components are required to build and run this project. Download the version of .NET Core SDK specified in global.json or update the SDK version in global.json to the version that is installed.
```

I have also installed .net core sdk on my machine.

[image: sdk installation]

Comment: Which build system did you use? vNext or XAML? Did you restart the build agent after install the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you can build the project directly in VS, if that doesn't work,

please follow below steps to fix the issue: See details [here](https://simplyaspnet.blogspot.com/2017/05/problem-if-you-open-orcreate.html).

1. Go to **Programs and Features**, find "**Microsoft Dotnet CLI for Windows
   (1.0.0.XXXX)**" then uninstall. This is most common cause of issue
   sometime alone this fix works. If nothing found then you are good to
   go to next step.
2. Instal latest **Nuget Manager Extension** from this [location](https://dist.nuget.org/visualstudio-2015-vsix/v3.5.0-beta/NuGet.Tools.vsix).
3. Reinstalled Tooling

- You should uninstall previous dotnet sdks before using RC2. Go to control panel > programs and features.
- You should have the following two packages installed (only! nothing else named "**Microsoft .NET Core** ...").if you found previous versions then remove old version. Then repair correct version.

4. Do `dnvm uninstall` on all version of runtime

- Open “Package Manager Console” (Tools > Nuget Package Manaager > Package Manager Console)
- Type `dnvm uninstall`

5. Delete all old .xprojs files

- You can delete all the `.xproj` files from your solution directory and after deleting open the `project.json` file  and press “**ctrl +s**“  keys to save the `projects.json` file, this will generate a fresh .xproj file

Comment: @Kaushal Solanki Have you resolved your issue by above workaround?